# Webpack externals not requiring

Tags: amazon-web-services, webpack, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

In my environment (aws-lambda) I have the aws-sdk set up, so in the webpack.config i've added:

```
externals: {
    'aws-sdk': 'aws-sdk'
  },
```

When building it seems to set it as `module.exports = aws-sdk;` instead of `module.exports = require('aws-sdk');` weird thing was it was working fine before, just randomly stopped, any ideas?

(using serverless-webpack and webpack)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally figured out by finding these docs: https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#externals

Had to have `output: { libraryTarget: "commonjs" },` set